# onclick event for a dynamically created div

Tags: jquery

I am using a jQuery audio player plugin called Soundmanager2
It dynamically ads play buttons in the DOM.
I am trying to ad onclick event for this button.

html

```
<div class="ui360"><a href="track1.m4a">Track1</a></div>
```

After button is added dynamically in the DOM it looks like this

```
<div class="ui360">
<div class="sm2-360ui"><canvas class="sm2-canvas hi-dpi" width="50" height="50"></canvas> <span class="sm2-360btn sm2-360btn-default"></span> <div class="sm2-timing alignTweak"></div> <div class="sm2-cover"></div></div>
<a href="track1.m4a">Track1</a></div>
```

my code :

```
$('.sm2-360ui').live(click,function(){
  alert("Playing");
});
```

Comment: `live` is dead, just check the DOC... That's said, you should write it: `$('.sm2-360ui').live("click",function(){...});`

Answer (score 2):

This is called event "delegation"

```
$(document).on('click','.sm2-360ui', function(){
  alert("Playing");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ui360').on('click','.sm2-360ui',function(){
  alert("Playing");
});
```